# Access Parent Record from child SOQL - APEX

Tags: apex, soql, execute-anonymous

This question seems silly but i am really stuck! I want to get the Account name and Account Rating for my contacts via Apex code, but instead of Account name and rating, it returns the accountId! I run the code in anonymous Console.
Any ideas of what i am doing wrong?

```
List<sObject> contacts = [select id, name, AccountId, Account.Name, Account.Rating from Contact];
system.debug(contacts);
```

But in the list returned as you can see, Account Name and Rating are not displayed. [image]

Comment: Check FLS on those fields

Comment: Hi Rahul, My user has access in those fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just how the Developer console shows the details. It does not show any parent details but you are actually getting those details.

```
List<Contact> contacts = [select id, name, AccountId, Account.Name, Account.Rating from Contact];
system.debug(contacts); 

for (Contact individualContact: contacts){
    System.debug(individualContact.Account.Name); // Should get the value here
}
```

Comment: Thanks manjit5190!!!